# require do php não funciona

Tags: php, amazon-aws

Estou com um site php hospedado em um servidor linux na AWS, no servidor local, que é windows, ele está funcionando normalmente, porém hospedado neste outro servidor ele não funciona os requires.

Estou chamando as páginas assim:

```
require_once '../Model/model.php';
```

Para testes, eu coloquei apenas esse código na página mesmo, e a página da este erro:
[image: Erro esta página não está funcionando]

Se eu dou um `header('location: ../Model/model.php')`ele redireciona para esta página certa, porém o `require` não funciona, alguém poderia me dar uma luz, grato desde já!

Edit: Como pedido, segue abaixo a estrutura das pastas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O arquivo que tem esse código do require está dentro da pasta `Controller`, e o arquivo requisitado, dentro da `Model`

Comment: Verifique se não tem problema com letras maiusculas e minusculas no código e nos nomes dos arquivos.

Comment: @rray, sim, pensei que poderia ser isto e está correto, tanto que no header ele redireciona

Comment: Já tentou utilizar a constante __DIR__ antes do require? Por exemplo: require_once __DIR__ . '../Model/model.php'; . Daqui a pouco o erro do require é ao encontrar o arquivo. __DIR (http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: pode ser, vou dar uma verificada, obrigado

Comment: @elvex coloquei assim: require_once _ _DIR_ _ '../Model/model.php'; porém continuou a página sem responder(o DIR com 2 underline e sem os espaços entre eles)

Comment: @LeonardoWalbrinch Clique em **[edit]** e poste a estrutura dos seus arquivos. Fica mais fácil.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, editei e coloquei uma foto e uma descrição de como está a estrutura.

Comment: @LeonardoWalbrinch , caso seu *controller* seja chamado pelo *index.php*, use `require_once 'Model/model.php';`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, ele é chamado pela página `login.php`, dentro da pasta `View`. Outra coisa estranha é que ele não passa dessa requisição, abaixo dela coloquei para dar um `echo "a"` e esse `a` não apareceu, porém se eu coloco antes do `require` ele aparece.

Comment: Usa `echo __DIR__` para saber em qual diretório tu estás.

Comment: Está em `/var/www/html/Controller`, me equivoquei antes, está em ´Controller´, não em ´View´

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achei a solução para o problema, o path padrão do php não estava configurado, tive que ir no `php.ini`, achar a linha que tem `include_path`, ela estava comentada, então eu descomentei e alterei para o caminho da pasta raíz do meu projeto.

No meu caso ficou assim:

`include_path = "/var/www/html/"`

Depois só reiniciei o serviço e funcionou. Valeu a todos que ajudaram!